# Failed to distribute private collection in Hyperledger Fabric

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, blockchain, ibm-blockchain

I am setting up a custom Hyperledger Fabric v1.2 blockchain network with 3 peers and 3 orgs using a private data collection. The side database is CouchDB. I use fabric-node-sdk to connect to the blockchain. The chaincode is instantiated without any errors but it is not possible to invoke a chaincode method that puts data into the collection.

The following error is displayed in the docker log of the peer that instantiated the chaincode and that is also the endorsing peer of the transaction:

```
> 2018-09-21 13:32:52.163 UTC [gossip/privdata] func1 -> ERRO 036 Failed disseminating private RWSet for TxID e2f0a03885bd31232042a19ff8a7eb36cef92f8a6ed24fcb0e3eed2f52b5c037 , namespace contract collection collection0 : Requested to send to at least 3 peers, but know only of 0 suitable peers.

>2018-09-21 13:32:52.163 UTC [gossip/service] DistributePrivateData -> ERRO 037 Failed to distributed private collection, txID e2f0a03885bd31232042a19ff8a7eb36cef92f8a6ed24fcb0e3eed2f52b5c037 channel coachannel due to Failed disseminating 1 out of 1 private RWSets
```

Note that the required peer count for the collection is 3. Obviously the data are not even stored in the side db of the endorsing peer itself even though  each peer has its own couchdb container.

The couchdb containers log an error like the following. Apart from that they seem to work properly.

```
>[notice] 2018-09-21T16:26:38.406978Z nonode@nohost <0.318.0> -------- chttpd_auth_cache changes listener died database_does_not_exist at mem3_shards:load_shards_from_db/6(line:403) <= mem3_shards:load_shards_from_disk/1(line:378) <= mem3_shards:load_shards_from_disk/2(line:407) <= mem3_shards:for_docid/3(line:91) <= fabric_doc_open:go/3(line:38) <= chttpd_auth_cache:ensure_auth_ddoc_exists/2(line:187) <= chttpd_auth_cache:listen_for_changes/1(line:134)
[error] 2018-09-21T16:26:38.407028Z nonode@nohost emulator -------- Error in process <0.319.0> with exit value:
{database_does_not_exist,[{mem3_shards,load_shards_from_db,"_users",[{file,"src/mem3_shards.erl"},{line,403}]},{mem3_shards,load_shards_from_disk,1,[{file,"src/mem3_shards.erl"},{line,378}]},{mem3_shards,load_shards_from_disk,2,[{file,"src/mem3_shards.erl"},{line,407}]},{mem3_shards,for_docid,3,[{file,"src/mem3_shards.erl"},{line,91}]},{fabric_doc_open,go,3,[{file,"src/fabric_doc_open.erl"},{line,38}]},{chttpd_auth_cache,ensure_auth_ddoc_exists,2,[{file,"src/chttpd_auth_cache.erl"},{line,187}]},{chttpd_auth_cache,listen_for_changes,1,[{file,"src/chttpd_auth_cache.erl"},{line,134}]}]}
```

Why are no private data stored in the side dbs and why does dissemination fail?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order for private data collections to work, you need to set up cross-organization gossip.  This means you'll need to make sure that you add the anchor peer(s) for each org to your channel configuration.  You can find all of the required information in the docs, but at a high level you need to add anchor peers in your configtx.yaml file for each org and then after ordering service is running and the channel has been created, each org will need to perform a channel update to add their anchor peers.  https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.2/build_network.html walks you through these steps.

Comment: Thank you for this very useful hint! Indeed the channel was not updated to include the anchor peers. Now it works fine.

Comment: Excellent ... happy to help

Comment: oh thank you so much @GariSingh I was spending the whole weekend on the problem and finally i got to resolve it by 'just' running updates after bringing up the network

Comment: how do you add the anchor peer using the node sdk? I understand how to do it using the cli container but am looking to automate with node sdk

Comment: @Moriarty, take a look at https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/blob/release-1.4/balance-transfer/app/update-anchor-peers.js